# LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, null, libgdx

I've a problem with a Null Pointer Error in my LibGdx application (Java). I've research all my code and nothing, the main problem is that the **java.lang.NullPointerException** appear before the `batch.draw()` and `stage.draw()` method is called many times *(execution error)* not immediately.

Here's the error:

```
: here2
: here3
: here2
: here3
: here2
: here3
: here2
: here3
: here2
: here3
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.draw(SpriteBatch.java:598)
    at com.platanobit.actors.Delivery.draw(Delivery.java:60)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.drawChildren(Group.java:110)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.draw(Group.java:57)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.draw(Stage.java:128)
    at com.platanobit.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:24)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:223)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

Here's the the code of line 60 (com.platanobit.actors.Delivery.draw(Delivery.java:60):

```
@Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

        if (dodging) {
            batch.draw(dodgingTexture, screenRectangle.x, screenRectangle.y + screenRectangle.height / 4, screenRectangle.width,
                    screenRectangle.height * 3 / 4);
        } else if (hit) {
            // When he's hit we also want to apply rotation if the body has been rotated
            batch.draw(hitTexture, screenRectangle.x, screenRectangle.y, screenRectangle.width * 0.5f,
                    screenRectangle.height * 0.5f, screenRectangle.width, screenRectangle.height, 1f, 1f,
                    (float) Math.toDegrees(body.getAngle()));
        } else if (jumping) {
            batch.draw(jumpingTexture, screenRectangle.x, screenRectangle.y, screenRectangle.width,
                    screenRectangle.height);
        } else {
            // Running
            stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if(batch != null){
            batch.draw(runningAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true), screenRectangle.x, screenRectangle.y,
                    screenRectangle.getWidth(), screenRectangle.getHeight());
            } else {
                Gdx.app.log("", "here");
            }
        }
        Gdx.app.log("","here2");
    }
```

And here is the code from line 24 (GameScreen.java):

```
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        // Clear the screen
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Update the stage
        stage.draw();
        Gdx.app.log("","here3");
        stage.act(delta);
    }
```

NOTE: Please look at the `Gdx.app.log("","Here");` code for debug purpose. If someone need something else please help me :/

Comment: Have got debugged it to make sure you're not passing in a null somewhere?

Comment: Yes, i did, i put some code like if (batcher != null) and apparently there isn't null variables, but if you see the method batch.draw() and stage.draw() is called 3 times and later is the null pointer :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check to make sure SpriteBatch is initialized before being passed into this method, and make sure you have called SpriteBatch.begin(); If this is not the problem please specify exactly what line is Delivery.java:60

Comment: this is line 60: batch.draw(runningAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true), screenRectangle.x, screenRectangle.y,

Comment: Put in a check to make sure this is not returning null runningAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true)

Comment: Look at the code that i post, is a check if(batch != null){

Comment: I meant check to make sure the texture returned by runningAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true) is not null

Comment: I'll check and let you know

Comment: Hey i found my error :D, my problem was related to my constant CHARACTERS_ATLAS_PATH that had my atlas (.txt) file, apparently was poorly formatted, i fix it and everything in order compiling xD thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

In libgdx before drawing anything on screen you should start the spriteBatch and after drawing you should end the Sprite batch.A Batch is used to draw 2D rectangles that reference a texture (region). The class will batch the drawing commands and optimize them for processing by the GPU.
To draw something with a Batch one has to first call the begin() method which will setup appropriate render states. When you are done with drawing you have to call end() which will actually draw the things you specified.

```
 public void render(SpriteBatch batch){
 batch.begin();
 stage.draw();
 sprite.draw(batch);
 batch.end();
```